# Why do many p-block dioxide gases dissolve in water to form acids?

Tags: acid-base, oxides

I find that many gases of the form $\ce{MO_2}$ like $\ce{SO2}$ , $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ dissolve in water to form acids. This observation has many different practical implications, for example, it is due to sulphur dioxide and nitrogen dioxide mixing with water vapour in air that acid rain is formed.

My question is why does mixing of gases into water make them into aqueous acids?

Comment: May be due to high electronegative ness of $\ce{S,C,N}$ (compared to metal oxides they make bases) those atoms are combined to $\ce{O}$ even more electronegative atom, Having a $\ce{H}$ to $\ce{O}$ will reduce this effect even better acid give away the proton and makes the acid anion more stable $\ce{O}$ having a minus charge.

Comment: That is a good way to think about @Avon97

Comment: It isn't true *in general*. Some, well-known, gases do form acids but many others do not. So the question really should read "why do **some** gases dissolve in water to form acids".

Comment: Usually non-metal oxides are reacting with water to produce acids. Some do not react at all, but none produce an hydroxide or a base, in contact with water. To my knowledge, this can be considered as a definition of non-metals.

Comment: As noted by matt_black and Maurice, one example I could think of is chlorine dioxide($\ce{ClO2}$). It doesn't hydrolyze in water. Hence, it is handle as a dissolved gas solution in water.